# Only last element of C array saving

Tags: c

I'm pretty new to C, and I was screwing around with some things that we were doing in class. But I've run across a problem:

```
srand(time(NULL));
for (counter = 0; counter < 7; counter = counter + 1);
{
    stats[counter] = abs(rand() % max); 
}
```

When I go to print these elements, however, only the last one makes any sense, everything else is `-858993460`

```
printf("Health:                 %d\n", stats[0]);
printf("Armor:                  %d\n", stats[1]);
printf("Damage:                 %d\n", stats[2]);
printf("Critical Strike Shance: %d\n", stats[3]);
printf("Critical Strike Damage: %d\n", stats[4]);
printf("Dexterity:              %d\n", stats[5]);
printf("Strength:               %d\n", stats[6]);
printf("Luck:                   %d\n", stats[7]);
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't assign anything to `stats[7]` though

Comment: Please show the rest of your program, you are probably populating a different `stats` array, or whatever you populate gets out of scope.

Comment: Post all the code including the declaration of `stats`, otherwise there is no point to anyone else speculating about it.

Comment: Given that `rand()` cannot return negative values, the `abs()` call only makes sense in the somewhat unintuitive case where `max` is negative.

Comment: The format specifier `%d` only works if the `stats[0]` values are `int`s. If they're declared as a different type, the table [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) explains which one to use.

Comment: Did your class advise to loop until `counter < lastElement` and writing `counter = counter + 1`? The former misses out an element, and the latter is so non-idiomatic that I can't remember the last time I ever saw it in C code. So I would hope not.

Comment: Please show us an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Also show how `max` is defined and set.

Comment: yeah, the abs() is leftover from when i was testing for the cause, thinking that maybe it was just giving me the same negative number. The < instead of <= was because when I had <=, none of them would be assigned. However, @Mike has answered it. I can't see how to mark it as answer though. Thanks for all the helps

Comment: @tkausl your comment about not assigning to `stats[7]` is exactly wrong -- that's the only thing assigned to! (see the accepted answer).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a semi-colon at the end of your for loop line.

```
for (counter = 0; counter < 7; counter = counter + 1);
                                                     ^^^^
```

that makes the following block afterwards execute only once. as it is not in the for loop.

Comment: Ahhh, so then the assignment happens to the post-loop index, `[7]`. Well spotted! (Shame about the rest of us ;-)

Comment: Wow!  Good eyes!  And only the "last" one gets filled in because `counter` is 7 *after* the loop exits.  @Wintermute Please note the counter will *never* be 7 *inside* the loop.